# Deployed web application long ajax wait (ttfb) time

Tags: ajax, web-applications, amazon-ec2, production-environment

I have a web application deployed on a ec2 server.

One of my pages uses an ajax call (triggered by a user's click) to call a servlet on my server that gets some data from my database (MySQL DB hosted on RDS) and then performs some methods on it.

On my development environment (ie: server and database server are on my pc), the wait (TTFB) time that my browser (Chrome/Firefox) shows is about 75 ms.
However, on my production environment(ec2 & RDS), the wait time is 350 ms.

When I measure the time elapsed between the start of the servlet that processes the ajax call and the end of it, the time elapsed is 70 ms (the time is the same both on my production environment and on my development environment). Meaning that it is not the server or the DB that is causing this lag.

Any suggestions on what is causing this lag? Is this latency? How can this be fixed? 
The only solution that I can think of at the moment is retrieving this information when the page is loaded as opposed to in response to the user's click.

Thank you.

Comment: I think that I have a similar problem, I have a crawler which is very slow on my ec2 (TTFB). On dev and on another web server (1&1) I have no latency. I have test a lot of things in vain (php.ini, upgrade..). Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I still have not implemented any changes but I think my issue was caused by latency. One possible solution might be changing the location of my ec2 instance as it is pretty far from me. Another solution will be eliminating the ajax calls and loading information on page load instead. I can update how these solutions worked out once I implement them.

Comment: When you say "changing the location" it's about AWS Region ? because I already tried this and nothing had change. In my case it's not an Ajax call it's a crawler so there is no other way to load this. I have ask my question on server fault I will see.
http://serverfault.com/questions/746513/latency-wait-ttfb-on-ec2